# Render custom content in sheet cell (PrimeFaces Extensions)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, handsontable, primefaces-extensions

I have another question regardless PF Extensions. Is it possible for example in one particular column to display custom (generic) column type. For example datePicker, Textarea, DecimalNumber, just Text or DropDown Menu. So for every single row it can be different content in this column. Is this idea possible or not really? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been raised before and its not so simple with the HandsonTable.  Its doable just not simple.

See: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/136